# Telegram: Send message to private group with bot

Tags: api, telegram, chatbot, mql4

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/myQjv.jpg)

I want to send a message to the private group and the message above appears to me, remove the chat_id from telegram web and add "-100".

When I make the change from public to private, If I get a message, but after that none comes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try changing [privacy mode](https://core.telegram.org/bots#privacy-mode), since your bot might not have the permission to see your messages, botfather is your friend ;)

Comment: I turn off? 
Privacy mode (https://core.telegram.org/bots#privacy-mode) is enabled for PLLSignals @PLLSignals_bot.

Comment: Is currently enable

Comment: ( a messge wih / at the beginning will always reach the bot ;) , this way you can test if you see anything )